# Как сделать обертку для Java метода из другой схемы?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle12c

Есть две схемы:

- `schema_one`

  - `functions.fn_run_java_wrap`
- `schema_two`

  - `java_sources.java_code`

Возможно ли сделать обертку для Java метода из другой схемы?

Пробовал так:

```
create or replace function schema_one.fn_run_java_wrap(
    p_one in varchar2, p_two in varchar2, p_three in varchar2) return clob 
    AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'schema_two.java_code.method(
        java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) return Clob';
```

Но получаю ошибку о том, что такой класс `shema_two/java_code` не существует.

Что я делаю не так?
Есть ли другие способы запустить java-code из другой схемы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, так нельзя: `schema_two.java_code.method`, разрешения имён не применимы к классам.

Как сказано в подглаве [Defining Call Specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdev/defining-call-specifications.html#GUID-61370303-0F46-4FAC-8CDB-EBC42F08AE68):

> A call specification and the Java method it publishes **must reside in the same schema**, unless the Java method has a `PUBLIC` synonym.

Или сделайте обертку для Java-метода в той же схеме и дайте права не выполнение другий схеме. Или создайте публичный синоним, как в этом воспроизводимом примере:

```
create or replace and compile java source named schm.testnop AS
public class TestNop
{
    public static String nop (String s) {
        return s;
    }
}
/
create public synonym "TestNop" for schm."TestNop"
/
create or replace function nop (s varchar2) return varchar2
as language java name 'TestNop.nop (java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
/
select nop('abc') res from dual
/

RES
--------
abc
```